# git rebase --onto works with tags?

Tags: git, rebase

After some thinking I think I have a similar case of rebase as the one in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) although with other branch names.

[image]

Here the docs say to apply

```
git rebase --onto master next topic
```

to get

[image]

In my case I have a branch called develop where master in the figure is, and a branch called MyFeature where topic is in the figure. In the point where "next" is I don't have a branch but I have a tag  "OLDdevelop"

Can I apply git rebase --onto here without expressly creating a branch in the "next" position?

Comment: Tags and branches are just nicknames for commits.  Your tag has to be in SOME branch somewhere.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, it is on the branch MyFeature but it is not the top.

Comment: I asked the chatGTP and it says it is not possible, I prefer a human expert knowledge. So can I use the branch name in the second position?

Comment: According to the doc, "next" and "topic" have to be branches, but the `--onto` can be any commit.  It's pretty easy to form a new branch there.

Comment: For me only `topic` need to be a branch because that is the only reference that will be updated. But you would have your answer quicker by trying. There is no real risk and git will complain before doing something if it's not good.

Comment: The questions stems from being afraid to destroy work. You can always try things out in a new repository to test your theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `git rebase` with tags (any ref really: tags, branches (branch heads), commits). So something like

```
git rebase --onto tag1 tag2 mybranch
```

is totally fine. Even `git rebase --onto tag1 tag2 somecommit` works, but you will end up in *detached head* state.

The full form of `git rebase` is:

```
git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream> <branch>
```

The man page contains this about [`--onto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---ontoltnewbasegt):

> `--onto <newbase>`
>
> Starting point at which to create the new commits. If the `--onto` option is not specified, the starting point is `<upstream>`. *May be any valid commit*, and not just an existing branch name.
> [emphasis mine]

and about [`<upstream>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt-ltupstreamgt):

> `<upstream>`
>
> Upstream branch to compare against. *May be any valid commit*, not just an existing branch name. Defaults to the configured upstream for the current branch.
> [emphasis mine]

A tag (usually) points to a commit, so you can use a tag in place of a commit. The tag will be peeled to reach the commit. Git calls these types of refs [*commit-ish*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefcommit-ishacommit-ishalsocommittish):

> **commit-ish (also committish)**
>
> A commit object or an object that can be recursively dereferenced to a commit object. The following are all commit-ishes: a commit object, a tag object that points to a commit object, a tag object that points to a tag object that points to a commit object, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream> <branch>
```

Here are some pseudo-commands that explain how this `git rebase` works.

```
# Checkout <branch>
git checkout ${branch}

# Reset it to <newbase>
git reset ${newbase} --hard

# Get the commits that are to be applied
commits=$(git rev-list ${upstream}..${branch})

# Apply these commits onto the newbase one by one
for commmit in $commits;do
    git cherry-pick $commit
done
```

It doesn't matter if the 3 parameters are branches, tags, commits, or other [commit-ish](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefcommit-ishacommit-ishalsocommittish) in the above pseudo-commands except the first command. At all events, the commits are applied, and a new log graph is created.

`git checkout $branch` behaves differently whether `$branch` is a branch or not.

```
# A branch in short format
git checkout topic
git branch
* topic

# A branch in other formats, or a non-branch ref
git checkout refs/heads/topic  # a branch in long format
git branch
* (HEAD detached at refs/heads/topic)

git checkout refs/tags/foo  # a tag in long format
git checkout foo  # a tag in short format
git checkout 5b74449ba231d4750743c2b5c00ddc2535fab38e  # a commit
git checkout refs/changes/22/339822/1  # a Gerrit ref
git checkout refs/merge-requests/99/head  # a Gitlab merge-request ref
```

The first switches to the branch `topic`, and the others lead to a detached HEAD.

Say `topic` points at the commit `a4f6f0e8cabe00011f5fc27176284c30575c136f`.

Before `git-rebase`,

```
* 8a73f8b (master) e
* 0271872 d
* 5b53145 c
| * a4f6f0e (topic) n
| * 046efc5 m
| * 544582f (next) g
| * f6516cf f
|/
* 7f2ea62 b
* 42dee2c root
```

After `git-rebase`,

```
# Case 1, "topic" is a branch in short format
git rebase --onto master next topic

git log --oneline --graph --decorate master next topic
* 5b74449 (HEAD -> topic) n
* 05f4607 m
* 8a73f8b (master) e
* 0271872 d
* 5b53145 c
| * 544582f (next) g
| * f6516cf f
|/
* 7f2ea62 b
* 42dee2c root



# Case 2, "topic" is a non-short-formatted-branch commit-ish, tags included
git rebase --onto master next a4f6f0e8cabe00011f5fc27176284c30575c136f
git log --oneline --graph --decorate HEAD master topic next

* 5b74449 (HEAD) n
* 05f4607 m
* 8a73f8b (master) e
* 0271872 d
* 5b53145 c
| * a4f6f0e (topic) n
| * 046efc5 m
| * 544582f (next) g
| * f6516cf f
|/
* 7f2ea62 b
* 42dee2c root
```

Both can work. Suppose the last commit is `5b74449` after the command. In Case 1, you don't need to do extra work. In Case 2, you need to reset `topic` to `5b74449`. Otherwise, `topic` still points at `a4f6f0e8cabe00011f5fc27176284c30575c136f`.

```
git checkout topic
git reset 5b74449 --hard
git log --oneline --graph --decorate master topic next

* 5b74449 (HEAD -> topic) n
* 05f4607 m
* 8a73f8b (master) e
* 0271872 d
* 5b53145 c
| * 544582f (next) g
| * f6516cf f
|/
* 7f2ea62 b
* 42dee2c root
```

In your case, the result is the same whether `$next` is a branch, a tag, a commit, or any other commit-ish.